# searching persons in a database from vb.net form

Tags: vb.net

I am building an application in VB.net and trying to get detail information from the database from de persons name that I write in a textbox, i've the following code (i get an eeror, can not find column "the name i give in the textbox").Can somebody help me??

**in the load of the form :**

```
    mijnKlant.KlantVullen()
    dgvKlanten.DataSource = mijnKlant.p_klant
    With Me.dgvKlanten
        .Columns("klant_id").DisplayIndex = 0
        .Columns("klant_id").HeaderText = "Klantnummer"
        .Columns("naam").DisplayIndex = 1
        .Columns("naam").HeaderText = "Naam"
        .Columns("voornaam").DisplayIndex = 2
        .Columns("voornaam").HeaderText = "Voornaam"
        .Columns("straat_nr").DisplayIndex = 3
        .Columns("straat_nr").HeaderText = "Straat en Nr."
        .Columns("postcode").DisplayIndex = 4
        .Columns("postcode").HeaderText = "Postcode"
        .Columns("naam_gemeente").DisplayIndex = 5
        .Columns("naam_gemeente").HeaderText = "Gemeente"
        .Columns("landen_naam").DisplayIndex = 6
        .Columns("landen_naam").HeaderText = "Land"
        .Columns("code_afwijkend_postadres").DisplayIndex = 7
        .Columns("code_afwijkend_postadres").HeaderText = "Postadres"
        .Columns("facturatieadres_straat_nr").DisplayIndex = 8
        .Columns("facturatieadres_straat_nr").HeaderText = "Facturatie Straat en Nr."
        .Columns("facturatieadres_postcode").DisplayIndex = 9
        .Columns("facturatieadres_postcode").HeaderText = "Facturatie Postcode"
        .Columns("facturatieadres_gemeente").DisplayIndex = 10
        .Columns("facturatieadres_gemeente").HeaderText = "Facturatie Gemeente"
        .Columns("facturatieadres_land").DisplayIndex = 11
        .Columns("facturatieadres_land").HeaderText = "Facturatie Land"
        .Columns("identiteitskaart_code").DisplayIndex = 12
        .Columns("identiteitskaart_code").HeaderText = "Identiteitskaartnummer"
        .Columns("postcode_id").Visible = False
        .Columns("land_id").Visible = False
        .Columns("land_id1").Visible = False
        .Columns("postcode_id1").Visible = False
        .Columns("postcode_gemeente").Visible = False

        .RowHeadersVisible = True
        .AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill
        .AllowUserToOrderColumns = False
        .AllowUserToResizeColumns = False
        .AllowUserToResizeRows = False
        .SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect

    End With
```

**on the presentation layer:**

```
    'enablen van buttons zodat de functie gebruikt kan worden
    Me.btnVerwijderKlant.Enabled = True
    Me.btnWijzigKlant.Enabled = True


    Dim strNaam As String
    strNaam = Me.txtNaam.Text 'geeft de naam in de databank

    'If outindex = -1 Then Exit Sub

    Dim myrw As DataRowView

    'functie aanroepen op DAL
    myrw = mijnKlant.klant_detail(strNaam)

    'binden van opgehaalde details aan de toegewezen controls
    Me.txtNaam.DataBindings.Add("Text", myrw, "naam")
    Me.txtNaam.DataBindings.Clear()
    Me.txtVoornaam.DataBindings.Add("Text", myrw, "voornaam")
    Me.txtVoornaam.DataBindings.Clear()
    Me.txtStraat.DataBindings.Add("Text", myrw, "straat_nr")
    Me.txtStraat.DataBindings.Clear()
    Me.cboGemeente.DataBindings.Add("Text", myrw, "naam_gemeente")
    Me.cboGemeente.DataBindings.Clear()
    Me.cbxAfwijkenAdres.DataBindings.Add("text", myrw, "code_afwijkend_postadres")

    'omzetting van string naar boolean
    If cbxAfwijkenAdres.Text = "T" Then
        Me.cbxAfwijkenAdres.Checked = True
        Me.cbxAfwijkenAdres.Text = "Postadres is gelijk aan het facturatieadres"
    End If

    If cbxAfwijkenAdres.Text = "F" Then
        Me.cbxAfwijkenAdres.Checked = False
        Me.cbxAfwijkenAdres.Text = "Postadres is gelijk aan het facturatieadres"
    End If

    'binden van opgehaalde details aan de toegewezen controls
    Me.cbxAfwijkenAdres.DataBindings.Clear()
    Me.txtPost.DataBindings.Add("Text", myrw, "postcode")
    Me.txtPost.DataBindings.Clear()
    Me.cboLand.DataBindings.Add("Text", myrw, "landen_naam")
    Me.cboLand.DataBindings.Clear()
    Me.txtID_Nr.DataBindings.Add("Text", myrw, "identiteitskaart_code")
    Me.txtID_Nr.DataBindings.Clear()
    Me.txt_F_Straat.DataBindings.Add("Text", myrw, "facturatieadres_straat_nr")
    Me.txt_F_Straat.DataBindings.Clear()
    Me.cbo_F_Gemeente.DataBindings.Add("Text", myrw, "facturatieadres_gemeente")
    Me.cbo_F_Gemeente.DataBindings.Clear()
    Me.cbo_F_Land.DataBindings.Add("Text", myrw, "facturatieadres_land")
    Me.cbo_F_Land.DataBindings.Clear()
    Me.txt_F_Post.DataBindings.Add("Text", myrw, "facturatieadres_postcode")
    Me.txt_F_Post.DataBindings.Clear()

    dgvKlanten.DataSource = mijnKlant.p_klant

    myrw = Nothing
End Sub
```

**on my datalayer:**

Public Sub KlantVullen()
        ' methode om dataview op te bouwen die dan later als bron zal dienen voor de zoekcombo in ons 
        Dim sqlStr As String = "SprKlantzoeken"
        Dim objConn As New SqlConnection(conStr.ConnString)
        objConn.Open()

```
    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlStr, objConn)

    'opvangen van foutmelding bij het ledigen van tabel klanten in dataset
    Try
        ds.Tables.Remove("klanten")

    Catch ex As ArgumentException

    End Try
    adapter.Fill(ds, "klanten")

    dt_klanten = ds.Tables("klanten")
    dv_klanten = dt_klanten.DefaultView
    dv_klanten.Sort = "klant_id"

    adapter.Dispose()
    adapter = Nothing

    objConn.Close()
    objConn.Dispose()

End Sub
' functie voor details op te vragen van klanten
Public Function klant_detail(ByVal i_index As String) As DataRowView
    Dim dv As DataView
    Dim anyrow As DataRowView
    dv = New DataView

    With dv
        .Table = ds.Tables("klanten")
        .AllowDelete = True
        .AllowEdit = True
        .AllowNew = True
        .RowFilter = "naam = " & i_index
    End With

    anyrow = dv.Item(0) 'geeft de eerste rij van de dataview dv

    ' Simple bind to a TextBox control
    dv = dt_klanten.DefaultView
    Return anyrow
    dv.Dispose()
    dv = Nothing

End Function
```

**Stored procedure in SQL database:**

USE [parken3]
GO
/***** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SprKlantzoeken]    Script Date: 07/13/2011 13:45:07 *****/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SprKlantzoeken] 
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

```
-- Insert statements for procedure here
```

select * from landen_lijst l , klant k ,  postcode p
where k.postcode_id = p.postcode_id
and k.land_id = l.land_id

END

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the line where you set .Rowfilter

```
With dv
    .Table = ds.Tables("klanten")
    .AllowDelete = True
    .AllowEdit = True
    .AllowNew = True
    .RowFilter = "naam = " & i_index      <---------
End With
```

Change it to this:

```
.RowFilter = "naam = '" & i_index.Replace("'", "''") & "'"
```